# Loading of data with user conditions power BI

Tags: business-intelligence, powerbi

I am developing a report application in Power BI desktop version. I successfully created a dataset using a query and applying the filters on result data. But Now i have to get data from database in real time with user filters i.e. dataset would be created on the basis of some inputs given by users. We need this as database size is quite huge and we can not load the data then apply filters and create reports.

Same can easily be done in Dot Net application but we have to achieve this on Power Bi.

Please suggest if this can be done.

Comment: please do add comments when you mark the question negative, to make someone understand where is the mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Query Parameters feature for this.  You add them in the Edit Queries window, from Home / Manage Parameters, then you can use them in Calculated columns or replacing a "hard coded" filter.

There's a detailed write up in a recent blog post:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/deep-dive-into-query-parameters-and-power-bi-templates/